# .NET Memory profiler optimization gains disappear in production

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, profiling

I've been using a memory profiler (.NET Memory Profiler from Scitech), meticulously going through various bits of code, and improving the garbage generation characteristics of my program. The counters show that garbage collection has been much reduced.

Or so it seems. Because when I run the program outside of the profiler, GCs seem to happen as often as they did before all those optimizations! I've done the trivial checks (it is the same program, compile options are the same, the machine/use is the same, and the inputs are all the same), and I'm wondering if there's something about how the profiler runs that I am not informed about. Naturally, the profiler must be placing hooks somewhere in the program to look at all the information that's displayed. But surely without these hooks, you'd think things would run more smoothly, rather than less?

Anyone seen anything like this before?

EDIT

I realize it's hard to get an answer when the question seems to unspecific. Just wondering if enough eyeballs will cause a useful hint to appear.

Comment: How are you "improving the garbage generation characteristics of (my) program"?

Comment: Well, I took on board some of the lessons from the video tutorials that are available on the SciTech site. Basically detective work using the various counters made available in the program. There's also a number of hints as to what might be causing memory problems, and I solved the ones I could find.

Comment: But is there a problem?  Does your app suffer from too much GC?

Comment: Well, it's a bit disappointing that I think I'm improving things (according to the profiler counters) and then when I put in on live, it doesn't seem to behave like the profiled version. Wondering what might cause such a discrepancy. The app itself has no hard targets, but I thought I'd reduced the frequency of GC by a factor of 10.

Comment: Frequency is time-based.  A memory profiler can slow down a program a lot.

Comment: The release version GC running without a debugger attached is very, very good at what it does. I've had an application where I've done a lot of work to reduce the amount of allocations (from 2.5 GiB down to just 100 MiB - it used some very inefficient 3rd party parsing library). In debug mode and in a debugger, the change was pretty significant. In release mode without a debugger, there was hardly any real difference. In my practice, I think that you should only really care about GCs when you have pinned / fixed pointers in memory. If not - let GC do it's job, it's surprisingly good at it.

Answer (score 0):

If your production version runs on computers with less memory, you'll hit the garbage collection threshold a lot more often, thus forcing more GC's.

.NET programs tend to sprawl in memory the more memory you give them, and usually development machines have *a lot* better resources than the machines your end users will end up running your programs on (which is perfectly fine and understandable, but you need to keep it in mind).

Comment: Ah, I should add that the code was profiled on the same machine, same user as the prod.

Comment: Garbage collection doesn't have anything to do with installed amount of RAM.

Comment: No, but the garbage collection rate does. Unless you hit the threshold to start collecting the garbage, the runtime will let "dead" objects pile on.

Comment: @Blindy While that is true, you shouldn't forget that there are limits (which are determined statistically at runtime) of memory allocations before GC runs. The default values are on the order of single MiBs, so they really don't have anything to do with total RAM available - that only becomes an issue if you actually need that much RAM at one time. If you keep allocating and deallocating, there's hardly any dependency on available RAM.